# Getting friends facebook wall post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-wall

Is this possible? I know how to do it from your own wall but not sure how or if you can do it from your friends wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For own wall feeds you must be doing.

graphurl/me/feeds.

for friends you should do.

graphurl/{friendId}/feeds

Comment: If this solves your query , then you should consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Just waiting the seven minutes